# OWA Web Preview: Content was blocked

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, owa

I have received an issue that the sharepoint cannot be viewed from searches.error is this:

> Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security
>   certificate. For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in
>   Internet Explorer Help.

so i checked the OWA Server:

[image]

then i checked the sharepoint server bindings and zone

the zones are the same: external-https. and i believe that the certificate used was valid as well.

am i missing something here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here is link for creating and using Certificate for OWA](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/justin_gao/2013/06/29/configuring-office-web-apps-server-communication-using-https/).

[Here is MS documentation for deploy OWA single-server with HTTPS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/deploy-office-web-apps-server#singlehttps).

**Certificates that are used by Office Web Apps Server must meet the following requirements:**

- The certificate must come from a trusted Certificate Authority and include the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of your Office Web Apps Server farm in the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) field. (If the FQDN is not in the SAN when you try to use the certificate, the browser will either show security warnings or won’t process the response.)
- The certificate must have an exportable private key. On single-server farms, this option is selected by default when you use the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager snap-in to import the certificate.
- The Friendly name field must be unique within the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store. If you have multiple certificates that share a Friendly Name field, farm creation will fail because the New-OfficeWebAppsFarm cmdlet will not know which of those certificates to use.
- The FQDN in the SAN field must not begin with an asterisk (*).
- The certificate properties and extensions do not matter. For example, customers have asked us whether Client Enhanced Key Usage (EKU) extensions or Server EKU extensions are required. Office Web Apps Server requires no particular certificate property or extension.

[Main introducing here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/configure-office-web-apps-for-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: Hi, note that this is an intranet. and also, i am not sure if i can request for a cert and the certificate was generated by the previous engineer through IIS.

Comment: This is doesn't matter that this is intranet, you need this kind of certificate for proper functional.

Comment: I dont have access to the adcs server unfortunately.

Comment: You havent already *.yourcompany.com the star certificate with private key?